# Getting a PHP contact form to work

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP, and trying to get a contact form to work on my website has proven a little difficult.
I've put a contact form onto my site; Everything functions properly other then sending the mail.
It's connected to my server on Godaddy, so not sure why it doesn't work.
Here is my code(changed a few of the names to remain anonymous.)

**HTML:**

```
<form id="contact.php" action="mywebsite" method="post">
                            <div class="div_input"><input type="text" name="c_name" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name';" /></div>
                            <div class="div_input"><input type="text" name="c_email" value="E-mail" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mail')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='E-mail';" /></div>
                            <div class="div_input"><input type="text" name="c_tel" value="Telephone" onfocus="if(this.value=='Telephone')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Telephone';" /></div>
                            <div class="div_textarea"><textarea name="c_text" rows="1" cols="1" onfocus="if(this.value=='Text')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Text';">Text</textarea></div>
                            <div class="div_btn"><input id="form_send" type="submit" name="c_send" value="" /></div>
                            <div class="div_warnings"></div>
                            <div class="loading"><img src="" alt="Loading" /></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['c_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['c_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['c_message'];

$mail_to = 'myemail';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'mywebsiteurl';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to myemail');
        window.location = 'mywebsiteurl';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I appreciate any help,

thank you.

Comment: are you sure "$_POST['cf_name'];" shouldn't be $_POST['c_name'];? And so on for the others...

Comment: is your php code on contact.php?

Comment: Jim, yeah sorry, I used the wrong script. They are supposed to be c_name. Edited. And yes my php is on contact.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In my html, I should have pointed action="" to my **php page** rather then my website.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, i didnt look further because it will throw undefined variable notices here and therefore your form wont work:

```
<input type="text" name="c_name" value="Name" ...

$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
```

Look at the names. Use error reporting for detecting such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I accidentally used a slightly different script. They should all be starting with c_, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="contact.php" id="mywebsite" method="post">
                            <div class="div_input"><input type="text" name="cf_name" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name';" /></div>
                            <div class="div_input"><input type="text" name="cf_email" value="E-mail" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mail')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='E-mail';" /></div>
                            <div class="div_input"><input type="text" name="cf_tel" value="Telephone" onfocus="if(this.value=='Telephone')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Telephone';" /></div>
                            <div class="div_textarea"><textarea name="cf_text" rows="1" cols="1" onfocus="if(this.value=='Text')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Text';">Text</textarea></div>
                            <div class="div_btn"><input id="form_send" type="submit" name="cf_send" value="" /></div>
                            <div class="div_warnings"></div>
                            <div class="loading"><img src="" alt="Loading" /></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Your name of the input fields are should be same when you access the data of your destination file.
form action is used to get your form data and process.so you should given your destination file name there!

sorry for my English!

i hope this help you!

Comment: Well, it might work, but you didnt tell him why it didnt work, so he will maybe come back tomorrow with the same question. You should always add an explanation what you actually did if you give someone a finished code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I accidentally used a slightly different script. They should all be starting with c_, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help? (add after existing $headers lines)

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64 \r\n";
$new_message_body= $base64contents = rtrim(chunk_split(base64_encode($body_message)));
mail($to, $subject, $new_message_body, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it out, nothing seems to have changed.